# Email is not taken or not sending a key through xpath

Tags: email, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am beginner in selenium webdriver and I am trying to login gmail account through xpath, now problem is that I have found an xpath for email and in these send a key. When we run the report the key sent to the password field instead of email, please help me how to resolve it.
Here is my code:

```
public class Usingxpath {

    static boolean c,c1,c2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver wD = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        wD.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        c=wD.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]")).isDisplayed();
        if(c==true){
            System.out.println("SignIn board is present");
        }
        c1=wD.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form")).isDisplayed();
        if(c1==true){
            System.out.println("Form is present");
        }
        c2=wD.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/input[15]")).isDisplayed();
        if(c1==true){
            System.out.println("email field is present");
        }
        WebElement emailInput= wD.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/input[15]"));
        emailInput.clear();
        emailInput.sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
        wD.quit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute xpathes. If you use some xpath browser plugin like Firepath for Firefox disable absolute xpath generating.

So your xpathes can be look like this:

1. //form[@id='gaia_loginform']//input[@id='Email'] - for email input
2. //form[@id='gaia_loginform']//input[@id='Passwd'] - for password input